# How can I temporarily store a pdf in Firebase filesystem?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, jspdf

I am creating a pdf using JSPDF on server-side, in NodeJS. Once done, I want to create a new folder for the user in Google Drive, upload the pdf to said folder, and also send it to the client-side (browser) for the user to view.

There are two problems that I'm encountering. Firstly, if I send the pdf in the response -via pdf.output()- the images don't display correctly. They are distorted, as though each row of pixels is offset by some amount. A vertical line "|" instead renders as a diagonal "\". An example is shown below.

[image] 
Before

[image] 
After

My workaround for this was to instead save it to the filesystem using doc.save() and then send it to the browser using fs.readFileSync(filepath).
However, I've discovered that when running remotely, I don't have file permissions to be saving the pdf and reading it. And after some research and tinkering, I'm thinking that I cannot change these permissions. This is the error I get:

*Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open './temp/output.pdf'

at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)

at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1194:35)

at Object.v.save (/workspace/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.node.min.js:86:50626)

etc...*

So I have this JSPDF object, and I believe I need to either, alter the permissions to allow writing/reading or take the jspdf object or, I guess, change it's format to one accepted by Google drive, such as a stream or buffer object?

The link below leads me to think these permissions can't be altered since it states: "These files are available in a read-only directory".
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system 
I also have no idea 'where' the server filesystem is, or how to access it. Thus, I think the best course of action is to look at sending the pdf in different formats.
I've checked jsPDF documentation for types that pdf.output() can return. These include string, arraybuffer, window, blob, jsPDF. 
https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output

My simplified code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const { jsPDF } = require('jspdf');

const credentials = require(credentialsFilepath);
const scopes = [scopes in here];
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email, null,
    credentials.private_key, scopes
);
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
//=========================================================================
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  var pdf = new jsPDF();

  // Set font, fontsize. Added some text, etc.
  pdf.text('blah blah', 10, 10);

  // Add image (signature) from canvas, which is passed as a dataURL
  pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 20);

  pdf.save('./temp/output.pdf');

  drive.files.create({
    resource: folderMetaData,
    fields: 'id'
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Store pdf in newly created folder
    var fileMetaData = {
      'name': 'filename.pdf',
      'parents': [response.data.id],
    };
    var media = {
      mimeType: 'application/pdf',
      body: fs.createReadStream('./temp/output.pdf'),
    };
    drive.files.create({
      resource: fileMetaData,
      media: media,
      fields: 'id'
    }, function(err, file) {
      if(err){
        console.error('Error:', err);
      }else{
        // I have considered piping 'file' back in the response here but can't figure out how
        console.log('File uploaded');
      }
   });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });

  // Finally, I attempt to send the pdf to client/browser
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.send(fs.readFileSync('./temp/output.pdf'));
})
```

Edit: After some more searching, I've found a similar question which explains that the fs module is for reading/writing to local filestore. 
[EROFS error when executing a File Write function in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083428/erofs-error-when-executing-a-file-write-function-in-firebase)

Comment: When you say image don't display correctly- This is happening on client side or where you save pdf file or on both sides? And your question only asks about sending  pdf to client side? On client side, do you want to save it or open it in the browser? Also, what are you using for front-end?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is happening on client side, as far as I've observed (I don't know how I can view the pdf on server-side). I'm only trying to open it in the browser to view, but with the option to download. For front-end, I believe we are just using HTML/CSS and JS

Comment: This file is saving temporarily on `./temp/filename` you should go and check it.

Comment: ./temp/filename is a local filepath. If I run the server locally then, yes, I can view it in that file. I have checked it and it looks fine. It works great. That's not the issue I'm having though. 
If I deploy the project and run it remotely, I no longer have permission to read/write to this directory. Presumably because I'm not longer accessing the local directory but a remote one, hosted by Firebase somewhere.

Comment: For that to work you should give permissions to write as long as I know about you can create permission in the firebase console.  I am not sure if [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions) thing will help but checking it is a good option.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a read through that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came to a solution after some further reading. I'm not sure who this will be useful for, but...

Turns out the Firebase filesystem only has 1 directory which allows you to write to (the rest are read-only). This directory is named tmp and I accessed it using the tmp node module [installed with: npm i tmp], since trying to manually reference the path with pdf.save('./tmp/output.pdf') didn't work.

So the only changes to my code were to add in the lines: 
*var tmp = require('tmp');*

*var tmpPath = tmp.tmpNameSync();*

and then replacing all the instances of *'./temp/output.pdf'* with *tmpPath*